# Getting build error in Drools embedded eclipse

Tags: eclipse, drools, jbpm, kie

I installed Drools in eclipse via jbpm drools integration 7.46 and added defined runtime as well but While creating new drools project its showing build error saying **"Errors running builder 'Drools Builder' on project 'myProject' could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kprojrct.models.KieModuleMarshaller java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**

I'm using jdk17 though. can someone please help me on this!

I tried building the project but its giving errors one error is mentioned below.

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2096)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSPTextHover.getHoverInfo(LSPTextHover.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.genericeditor.hover.CompositeTextHover.getHoverInfo2(CompositeTextHover.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$1.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:155)
```

Comment: "java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:386)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2096)
 at org.eclipse.lsp4e.operations.hover.LSPTextHover.getHoverInfo(LSPTextHover.java:73)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.genericeditor.hover.CompositeTextHover.getHoverInfo2(CompositeTextHover.java:60)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$1.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:155)" is the error in Error Log

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, delete the log (the button with the red `x`), reproduce the issue, and then select the new logged error(s) (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (using the `{}` button). The first part of the stack trace that you added to your question is not enough to know what causing it (`LSPTextHover` sounds you picked an unrelated error). It is important that you add the entire logged error, not just the stack trace.